# R How to find Patient Visit Interval

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a patient dataset that looks like this

```
ID | Visit Date | Category |
1  | 10/10/2019 | Derma    |
1  | 12/10/2019 | Derma    |
1  | 14/10/2019 | Derma    |
1  | 20/10/2019 | Eye      |
1  | 15/10/2019 | Eye      |
1  | 07/10/2019 | O&G      |
1  | 08/10/2019 | O&G      |
2  | 20/10/2019 | Derma    |
2  | 22/10/2019 | Derma    |
2  | 24/10/2019 | Derma    |
2  | 05/10/2019 | Eye      |
2  | 10/10/2019 | Eye      |
2  | 12/10/2019 | Eye      |
```

For each Patient, I'm trying to find the Visit Interval between each Visit Category which is defined like this: **The 2nd earliest visit date of all the Category value - The earliest visit date of all the Category values**

So for Patient 1, the earliest Visit Date is O&G at 07/10/2019 and the 2nd earliest Visit Date is Derma at 10/10/2019. So the Visit Interval is **3 days**.

For Patient 2, the earliest Visit Date is eye at 05/10/2019 and the 2nd earliest Visit Date is Derma at 20/10/2019. So the Visit Interval is **15 days**.

Expected result:

```
ID | Visit Date | Category | Visit Interval |
1  | 10/10/2019 | Derma    | 3 Days         |
1  | 12/10/2019 | Derma    | 3 Days         |
1  | 14/10/2019 | Derma    | 3 Days         |
1  | 20/10/2019 | Eye      | 3 Days         |
1  | 15/10/2019 | Eye      | 3 Days         |
1  | 07/10/2019 | O&G      | 3 Days         |
1  | 08/10/2019 | O&G      | 3 Days         |
2  | 20/10/2019 | Derma    | 15 Days        |
2  | 22/10/2019 | Derma    | 15 Days        |
2  | 24/10/2019 | Derma    | 15 Days        |
2  | 05/10/2019 | Eye      | 15 Days        |
2  | 10/10/2019 | Eye      | 15 Days        |
2  | 12/10/2019 | Eye      | 15 Days        |
```

Pls use the code below for entering the dataset into R:

```
library(readr)
df <- read_delim("ID | Visit Date | Category 
1  | 10/10/2019 | Derma    
1  | 12/10/2019 | Derma    
1  | 14/10/2019 | Derma    
1  | 20/10/2019 | Eye      
1  | 15/10/2019 | Eye      
1  | 07/10/2019 | O&G      
1  | 08/10/2019 | O&G      
2  | 20/10/2019 | Derma    
2  | 22/10/2019 | Derma    
2  | 24/10/2019 | Derma    
2  | 05/10/2019 | Eye      
2  | 10/10/2019 | Eye      
2  | 12/10/2019 | Eye", delim = "|", trim_ws = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first change `Visit Date` to actual date object, `arrange` date based on `ID` and `Visit Date`, for each `ID` create a `rank` column which defines the order, select first entry of two `Category` and get the difference between them.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(`Visit Date` = lubridate::dmy(`Visit Date`)) %>%
  arrange(ID, `Visit Date`) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(rank = match(Category, unique(Category)), 
         interval = diff(`Visit Date`[match(1:2, rank)])) %>%
  select(-rank)


#      ID `Visit Date` Category interval
#   <dbl> <date>       <chr>    <drtn>  
# 1     1 2019-10-07   O&G       3 days 
# 2     1 2019-10-08   O&G       3 days 
# 3     1 2019-10-10   Derma     3 days 
# 4     1 2019-10-12   Derma     3 days 
# 5     1 2019-10-14   Derma     3 days 
# 6     1 2019-10-15   Eye       3 days 
# 7     1 2019-10-20   Eye       3 days 
# 8     2 2019-10-05   Eye      15 days 
# 9     2 2019-10-10   Eye      15 days 
#10     2 2019-10-12   Eye      15 days 
#11     2 2019-10-20   Derma    15 days 
#12     2 2019-10-22   Derma    15 days 
#13     2 2019-10-24   Derma    15 days
```

`rank` is the order in which each `Category` appear for each `ID`, so for `ID = 1` , `O&G` has `rank` as 1, `Derma` has `rank` as 2 and `Eye` has `rank` as 3. For `interval`, we select 1st entry of first 2 (`1:2`) ranks i.e (`2019-10-07` and `2019-10-10`) and take the difference between them.

Comment: could u explain this part: ````mutate(rank = match(Category, unique(Category)), 
         interval = diff(`Visit Date`[match(1:2, rank)]))````

Comment: @spidermarn I updated the answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(`Visit Date` = as.Date(`Visit Date`, "%d/%m/%Y")) %>% 
  group_by(ID, Category) %>% 
  mutate(first_date_category = first(`Visit Date`, order_by = `Visit Date`)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(`Visit Interval` = nth(unique(first_date_category), 2, order_by = unique(first_date_category)) - first(unique(first_date_category), order_by = unique(first_date_category))) %>%
  select(-first_date_category)
```

Basically, we first create the column `first_date_category` which represents the first date for each group patient-category. Then we group only according to patient `ID`, we order chronologically the `unique` values of `first_date_category` and we take the difference between the second and the first date.

Output

```
# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
#       ID `Visit Date` Category `Visit Interval`
#    <dbl> <date>       <chr>    <drtn>          
#  1     1 2019-10-10   Derma     3 days         
#  2     1 2019-10-12   Derma     3 days         
#  3     1 2019-10-14   Derma     3 days         
#  4     1 2019-10-20   Eye       3 days         
#  5     1 2019-10-15   Eye       3 days         
#  6     1 2019-10-07   O&G       3 days         
#  7     1 2019-10-08   O&G       3 days         
#  8     2 2019-10-20   Derma    15 days         
#  9     2 2019-10-22   Derma    15 days         
# 10     2 2019-10-24   Derma    15 days         
# 11     2 2019-10-05   Eye      15 days         
# 12     2 2019-10-10   Eye      15 days         
# 13     2 2019-10-12   Eye      15 days
```